# Microsoft Teams Bot without Azure

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I've recently started digging into teams bot and from what I've learned so far, we cannot use our teams bot without azure. I just wanted to know whether I'm right or wrong.
If wrong, can you please tell me in detail how to create a bot that can listen to incoming messages and send messages to teams using python? Also if I were to use azure, will it be necessary for other people to be on azure to use my bot?

Comment: Please refer: 1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/quickstart-create-bot-with-azure
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned

Answer (score 6):

If you're really interested in the detail, I have a post on my blog that might be useful: https://hilton.giesenow.com/how-bot-calls-actually-work

In short though, to build a bot for Teams, you need to have your bot *registered* in the Microsoft Bot Framework Services engine, which you do via a registration in Azure. You can do this without the bot being *hosted* in Azure though - it can live on any https endpoint (e.g. hosted in AWS). You do still need *some* kind of hosting though, so Microsoft give you the option of creating the Bot Framework Services *AND* a hosting package combined - you just need to choose which option suits you when creating the bot in the Azure portal.

Separate to the hosting, you can code your bot in a variety of languages, using the bot builder sdk, and Python is definitely an option. See for example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-create-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python%2Cvs#prerequisites), and for each of the samples section in the page, choose the "python" language option.