# How to setup 3rd party basic authentication for a Microsoft Teams bot without Azure?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I have a web application that allows for basic authentication using email and password. I need to reuse this authentication method for a Teams bot I am setting up. I cannot seem to find any examples that show how to open a popup requesting for user credentials, authenticating the user and then sending a  card to authenticated users. The user credentials are stored on the server side.

Comment: This link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73703365/421195

Comment: Could you please refer this doc and let us know if it helps?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-oauth-provider

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT No it does not help. We use just Basic email password authentication and not Oauth . Also, we want to authenticate using a Teams Bot application

Comment: Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) for authentication is the recommended approach for building secure and scalable Teams apps. Azure AD does not support Basic Auth. And in fact, Microsoft is deprecating basic auth for Exchange Online as announced [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/exchange-online-basic-auth-deprecated).

Comment: We cannot move all our user identities into Azure AD. Is there any way to get some tech support on a call? The documentation is so vast.

Comment: If you have any business-critical issue which need immediate attention, please raise a support request [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=online)

Comment: Hello @coder0110 - You can enable authentication using third-party OAuth provider. Please refer this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab

Comment: Hello @coder0110 - Please refer this sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-complete-auth/csharp